# FutureBuilder not waiting for async function to load

Tags: flutter, dart

Edit 3: Here's what it looks like now

```
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    myFuture = genCode();
  }
```

```
Future<Uint8List> genCode() async {
print('This should be the start')
Obj o = await _getAsyncData();
print('This should be the end');
return await scanner.generateBarCode(o.str);
}

Future<Obj> _getAsyncData() async {
Obj o = await addObj();
print('Hello');
print(o.str);
return o;
}

Future<Obj> addObj() async {
final String url = 'APIURL';
final client = new http.Client();
final response = await client.post(
url,
headers: {HttpHeaders.contentTypeHeader: 'application/json',
);
print('Obj added. Received response.');
Obj o = Obj.fromJSON(json.decode(response.body));
print(o.str);
return o;
}
```

Prints

```
I/flutter (12991): This should be the start
I/flutter (12991): This should be the end
I/flutter (12991): Obj added. Received response.
I/flutter (12991): 12345
I/flutter (12991): Hello
I/flutter (12991): 12345
```

FutureBuilder widget goes straight to this block of code

```
if (snapshot.hasError) {
children = <Widget>[
Icon(
Icons.error_outline,
color: Colors.red,
size: 60,
),
Padding(
padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 16),
child: Text('Error: ${snapshot.error}'),
)
];
}
```

It shows the exclamation mark and prints on screen:

```
Error: NoSuchMethodError: The getter 'str' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: str
```

Somehow it's ignoring the fact that the async function is still running in the background.

```
FutureBuilder(
                  future: myFuture, // a previously-obtained Future<String> or null
                  builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
                    List<Widget> children;
                    if (snapshot.hasData) {
                      children = <Widget>[
                        QRDisplayWidget(title: '', bytes: snapshot.data),
                      ];
                    } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
                      children = <Widget>[
                        Icon(
                          Icons.error_outline,
                          color: Colors.red,
                          size: 60,
                        ),
                        Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 16),
                          child: Text('Error: ${snapshot.error}'),
                        )
                      ];
                    } else {
                      children = <Widget>[
                        SizedBox(
                          child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                          width: 60,
                          height: 60,
                        ),
                        const Padding(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 16),
                          child: Text('Awaiting result...'),
                        )
                      ];
                    }
                    return Center(
                      child: Column(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                        children: children,
                      ),
                    );
                  },
                ),
```

Original Code:

Error: The argument type 'Future Function(BuildContext,
AsyncSnapshot)' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Widget Function(BuildContext, AsyncSnapshot)'.

What am I missing? The code is exactly the same as the docs

```
                FutureBuilder<String>(
                  future: getQRStr(), // a previously-obtained Future<String> or null
                  builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<String> snapshot) async {
                    List<Widget> children;
                    if (snapshot.hasData) {
                      children = <Widget>[
                        QRDisplayWidget(title: '', bytes: getBytes(snapshot)),
                      ];
                    } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
                      children = <Widget>[
                        Icon(
                          Icons.error_outline,
                          color: Colors.red,
                          size: 60,
                        ),
                        Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 16),
                          child: Text('Error: ${snapshot.error}'),
                        )
                      ];
                    } else {
                      children = <Widget>[
                        SizedBox(
                          child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                          width: 60,
                          height: 60,
                        ),
                        const Padding(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 16),
                          child: Text('Awaiting result...'),
                        )
                      ];
                    }
                    return Center(
                      child: Column(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                        children: children,
                      ),
                    );
                  },
                ),
```

Edit: So I got the FutureBuilder to stop throwing the error, but the String value is still retrieved before the data is fetched.

```
  Future<String> getQRStr() async{
    String str = await _asyncFetchData();
    return Future.value(str); // return your response
  }

  Future<Uint8List> getBytes(AsyncSnapshot snapshot) async{
    return await scanner.generateBarCode(snapshot.data);
  }
```

Edit 2: 
I edited it to what I have right now. If I use Future on getBytes, I get `Error: The argument type 'Future<Uint8List>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Uint8List'`. Removing Future makes it run compile without errors but the app seems to be thrown into a state of perpetual refresh, constantly calling getQRStr().

Under the _asyncFetchData function, I have a print function that prints the data after successfully retrieving it before returning the value. That prints fine. But FutureBuilder prints that the value returned is null.

Comment: In your edit what do you mean by "data is fetched"? Additionally, you do not need to return `Future.value`. You can just do `return str`.

Comment: It seems like your edit is describing a different issue. If so, you should accept an answer on this question and make a new one for your new problem.

Comment: @ChristopherMoore I edited it for more clarity

Comment: From what I can see, you are still implementing the future in the `FutureBuilder` incorrectly. See my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot pass a `Future` to the `builder` parameter of the `FutureBuilder`. You can't `await` on anything in the `builder`.

As a solution you can make a new function like below and pass that to the `FutureBuilder`.

```
Future<Uint8List> genCode() async {
  return await scanner.generateBarCode(await getQRStr());
}
```

Other parts:

```
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    myFuture = genCode();
  }
......
                FutureBuilder(
                  future: myFuture, 
                  builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
                    List<Widget> children;
                    if (snapshot.hasData) {
                      children = <Widget>[
                        QRDisplayWidget(title: '', bytes: snapshot.data),
                      ];
                    } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
                      children = <Widget>[
                        Icon(
                          Icons.error_outline,
                          color: Colors.red,
                          size: 60,
                        ),
                        Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 16),
                          child: Text('Error: ${snapshot.error}'),
                        )
                      ];
                    } else {
                      children = <Widget>[
                        SizedBox(
                          child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                          width: 60,
                          height: 60,
                        ),
                        const Padding(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 16),
                          child: Text('Awaiting result...'),
                        )
                      ];
                    }
                    return Center(
                      child: Column(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                        children: children,
                      ),
                    );
                  },
                ),
```

Comment: How will I get it to wait for the async scanner.generateBarCode() function then?

Comment: QRDisplayWidget takes a regular Uint8List. Without transforming the string, I get the error ```Error: The argument type 'Future<Uint8List>' can't be assigned to the parameter type
'Future<String>'```

Comment: The line future: genCode() still throws the error ```Error: The argument type 'Future<Uint8List>' can't be assigned to the parameter type
'Future<String>'```

Comment: I fixed it by removing the <String> above too. But it's still doing the perpetual refresh. For some reason it's constantly calling getQRStr() over and over again.

Comment: @Josh What does "perpetual refresh" mean?

Comment: It's calling getQRStr() repeatedly with a million calls per second

Comment: @Josh That's expected with your current method of implementation. I made an edit to fix this to what you want.

Comment: @Josh I'm not sure that's possible. Could you show me what you're using?

Comment: @Josh Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214032/discussion-between-christopher-moore-and-josh).

Answer (score -1):

Delete async from your code then try again please.
But in this case you need to handle your QRDisplayWidget widget because it has await function for bytes, but you can declare it outside of builder then call it, something like below.

```
getBytes()async{
var snaphot.data;
 await scanner.generateBarCode(snapshot.data)
}    

FutureBuilder<String>(
                      future: getQRStr(), // a previously-obtained Future<String> or null
                      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<String> snapshot) {
                        List<Widget> children;
                    if (snapshot.hasData) {
                      children = <Widget>[
                        QRDisplayWidget(title: '', bytes: getBytes()),
                      ];
                    } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
```